# How to enable "Connect to Outlook" function in your custom list?

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, synchronization

How can I enable the functionality to sync my custom list with Outlook 2007 todo or calendar list? I assume it's possible with custom lists too, but I cannot find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge this is not possible. If you need to sync a todo list, create a task list. Then you can delete all the columns that don't interest you, and add whatever columns you want to use.

The same goes for calendar, if you want a list syncronised with your outlook calendar, then create a calendar list and customize it to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid so. I was hoping to enable it for my existing and filled with data custom list, but I think it's a no-go indeed.

Comment: Yearh, im sorry. If you set up a view on the new list with the same columns as in the old list, you can edit them in datasheet and practically copy the cells as if they were excel sheets.

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon Filip's great answer . . .

According to this [MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2008/08/30/connect-to-outlook-feature-is-missing-in-the-calendar-of-custom-calendar-list-definition.aspx), the custom list template has a different type designation (100) than the Task Template (106 in the article above, 107 in my research of SP2010).  This is what the UI looks at to disable the Outlook Sync button.  So, if your custom list is based on a custom content type you created then you can recreate your list to be Outlook compatible.

1. If your list already contains data, export it to Excel
2. Create a new list based on the Task template (instead of Custom)
3. Add your CT and delete the Task CT (if your content type is based on the Task CT i.e. has the columns) and any others your list doesn't need
4. Add any other columns your list needs but may not be part of your CT (or if you don't use a custom CT)
5. Use Datasheet view to copy and paste your data into the new list (observe column order)

Caveats: Not all data columns can be copied using this method (e.g. Attachments, system fields, etc.)

Hope this helps clarify

Answer (score 2):

This is available / possible (well it takes some programming to achieve it) - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231725/sync-list-with-outlook-only-with-items-in-current-view/1477355#1477355).

For my solution, I aggregate data between sites and sync them with outlook. There are some tricky things like to map item's uniqueId to integer ID (probably a database table with mappings) to refer to specific item correctly, but it's not impossible.

But it's not something you can use right away - coding required. However if you really, really need it, then it's a some-way to go.

Comment: Thank you for that. STSSync protocol handler seems interesting indeed.

Comment: And you can implement that simply if you work with a specific list.

Answer (score 2):

If your custom list is based off of a sharepoint list, then you can connect it to outlook by generating a link formatted based off the stssync protocol.

I created a custom list definition based off the events (Calendar) list.

It uses the base calendar list template plus some custom fields and forms.

I created a link formatted in accordance with the stssync protocol, and successfully connected it  with outlook:

stssync://sts/?ver=1.1&type=calendar&cmd=add-folder&base-url=[site url]&list-url=[your list url]&guid=[GUID of list]&site-name=[SiteName]&list-name=[ListName]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah not possible sadly.  Also, if you create custom columns in a task list or calender, Outlook won't sync those columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same issue and found that it cannot be done with the built in functionality that SharePoint has, but there is a 3rd party program that allows this to be done.  You can try with ProperSync.  It will allow you to connect the custom fields of a custom list from SharePoint and view and edit them using Outlook.

This is the link to the main site: http://propersync.com/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can override List Ribbon Button, which holds sync logic, and create your custom action on it.

Here is good article about creating ribbons: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2009/12/07/sharepointfoundationhowtoaddtabtoribbon.aspx

For List View OutlookSyncButton you should in CommandUIDefinition specify Location="Ribbon.List.Actions.ConnectToClient".
For Calendar View - you should specify Location="Ribbon.Calendar.Calendar.Actions.ConnectToClient".

Now, in CommandUIHandler/CommandAction you specifing JS code that connects to outlook  (simply I grab it from SP :)):

```
alert("Let's go!");

var listid = '{ListId}';           
var list;

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetParamsAndSync, 'sp.js');

function GetParamsAndSync()
{
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = clientContext.get_web();
  list = web.get_lists().getById(listid);
  clientContext.load(list);
  clientContext.load(web);

  rf = list.get_rootFolder()
  clientContext.load(rf);

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
      viewUrl=rf.get_serverRelativeUrl();
      ExportHailStormOverride('calendar','{SiteUrl}','{ListId}', web.get_title(),list.get_title(),viewUrl,viewUrl,'')
    }, 
    function() {alert('Error')});
}

//This function was taken from SharePoint sp.init.js
function  ExportHailStormOverride(type,weburl,guid,webname,listname,viewurl,passport,listrooturl,folderurl,folderid)
{ULSA13:;
    var strAppName=GetCookie('stsSyncAppName');
    var strIconName=GetCookie('stsSyncIconPath');
    var maxLinkLength=500;
    var maxNameLength=20;
    var link='stssync://sts/?ver=1.1'
            +'&amp;type='+escapeProperly(type)
            +'&amp;cmd=add-folder'
            +'&amp;base-url='+escapeForSync(weburl)
            +'&amp;list-url='+escapeForSync('/' 
            + makeAbsUrl(viewurl).substr(weburl.length+1)+'/')
            +'&amp;guid='+escapeProperly(guid);
    if (window.self.offlineBtnUser !=undefined)
        link+='&amp;user-id='+offlineBtnUser;
    var names='&amp;site-name='+escapeForSync(webname)
            +'&amp;list-name='+escapeForSync(listname);
    var context='';
    if (folderurl)
        context+='&amp;folder-url='
             + escapeForSync('/'+folderurl.substr(listrooturl.length+1));
    if (folderid)
        context+='&amp;folder-id='+folderid;
    if (link.length+names.length+context.length > maxLinkLength &amp;&amp;
        (webname.length > maxNameLength || listname.length > maxNameLength))
    {
        if (webname.length > maxNameLength)
            webname=webname.substring(0, maxNameLength-1)+'...';
        if (listname.length > maxNameLength)
            listname=listname.substring(0, maxNameLength-1)+'...';
        names='&amp;site-name='+escapeForSync(webname)
             +'&amp;list-name='+escapeForSync(listname);
    }
    link=link+names+context;
    var L_StssyncTooLong_Text='The name of site or list is too long. Make it shorter.';
    if (link.length > maxLinkLength)
        alert(L_StssyncTooLong_Text);
    else
    {
        try
        {
            window.location.href=link;

        }
        catch (e)
        {
            alert('Sync error.');
        }
    }
}
```