# Sync list with outlook only with items in current view

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, synchronization

Currently outlook takes all list data and synchronises it with outlook.

Is it possible and how to synchronise only items in a specific view? I`m only interested in my items in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a custom solution. One guy wrote [stssync protocol provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/pcreehan/archive/2008/06/10/two-way-stssync-protocol-server-for-outlook-2007.aspx) to synchronize Outlook against any DataTable.

This needs some custom implementation in SharePoint, however I`v managed to get my queried data to outlook.

I`m still working with some issues like how to get Body field rendered in Outlook, but if someone needs this functionality, then this protocol implementation is a nice start.

### Time has passed and there is another solution

The alternative is to use custom web service provider that would provide outlook only items that it needs.

See this question and answer: [Sharepoint task list and Outlook sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546811/sharepoint-task-list-and-outlook-sync)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible out-of-the-box. When connecting a list to Outlook it occurs at the list level, not at the view level.

There may be a product you can purchase that will do this. I've had a quick look around for you without success but hopefully someone else can help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do exactly what you are asking.

You could use the Content Query or Search Core Results Web Parts to get a filtered RSS feed which can be synced with Outlook. Of course, this is read-only so it might not be what you were after.