# Sharepoint task list and Outlook sync

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

I am trying to sync Sharepoint task list with Outlook. When the users connect the task list to outlook, the task for all users are visible in outlook. Rather than applying filtering in Outlook, can I provide a filtering at the source itself? There are considerable number of users for my application, it wouldn't be good to ask all users to apply filters on their own.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: insert alert(ctx.listName) and alert(ctx.view.toLowerCase()) to see if valid values are present. ctx may be null if you are viewing list within a webpart with full toolbar. Try to open the list.

Comment: @janis: I am getting the original list in outlook now. I am able to get the alert with the correct list id and view id and the problem I think is that the replace function on  itm.onMenuClick = itm.onMenuClick.replace(ctx.listName.toLowerCase(), ctx.view.toLowerCase()); is not working

Comment: @janis: When I disable the line itm.onMenuClick = itm.onMenuClick.replace(ctx.listName.toLowerCase(), ctx.view.toLowerCase()); Its retrieving the normal list, when i include it nothing is getting retrieved and the error remains. The get list method of the web service is acting fine. what are the other related methods that get triggered when connecting to outlook?

Comment: It means that you sucessfully connect to outlook. And outlook is then requestion sharepoint for items and then OutlookLists is probably crashing somwhere or not doing something as expected. Check if getListFromView method actually returns a list (finds a list by view id)

Comment: It does return a list, i checked with the id returned and the item count.

Comment: @janis: how about writing a code that will filter tasks based on current user and add these to outlook tasks using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook as and when a new task gets updated to outlook from sharepoint. package this as a bat file.

Comment: Could you please then see what response is being sent back to outlook and paste it in your question? Thank you.

Comment: @janis: see my question, I have added the request and response

Comment: It will not work in ie, because in global.asax file we redirect requests to "_vti_bin/lists.asmx" where useragent contains "Microsoft Office Outlook", we redirect to OutlookLists.asmx. With any other user agent it won't work, as lists.asmx doesn't know what to do with the view id. Please modify the OutlookLists.asmx with debug statements to see if the code gets called when using Outlook.

Comment: Yes its getting redirected to OutlookLists.asmx... The GetList method is triggering fine, i have log statements in there, but when it comes to the GetListItemChangesToken, its not getting trigerred. What did you mean by it will not work in ie???

Comment: GetList is from OutlookLists.asmx... could it be that this GetListChangesToken still takes the default lists.asmx???

Comment: You wrote "Here is the request in ie". I thought it is Internet Explorer. There is no such method GetListChangesToken, but there is GetListItemChangesSinceToken (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists_members(v=office.12).aspx). If GetListItems is triggered, then all other methods should be triggered by Outlook.

Comment: Yes I meant Internet Explorer, I was looking for the response when i click on 'Connect to Outlook'. I am not getting the GetListItems to trigger

Comment: You don't have to check response with IE, because if you pressed Connect To Outlook, you should see the sharepoint list in your outlook. What i mean with the response is i want to see what OutlookLists.asmx responds. You can do that with debugger or adding debug statements in, for example, GetListItemChangesSinceToken or GetListItems method to see what it sends back to outlook.

Comment: Ah fine! I will try that next...

Comment: Its working! I just removed few lines from the GetListItemSinceChangesToken function. The meeting instance objects were not needed for my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I`v asked the same question: [Sync list with outlook only with items in current view.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231725/sync-list-with-outlook-only-with-items-in-current-view). In this case it was possible to use stssync protocol to do whatever you want. It takes much effort (luckily someone already wrote an [implementation](http://stssyncprovider.codeplex.com/))

But there was another solution i ended up using - implementing a wrapper for Lists.asmx webservice and rewriting outlook requests (by using custom Global.asax file) to use this new webservice instead of Lists.asmx, that only queries specific view in a list.

```
if (ctx.Request.UserAgent.Contains("Microsoft Office Outlook") && path.ToLower().IndexOf("_vti_bin/lists.asmx") >= 0)
            {
                ctx.RewritePath("/_layouts/OutlookLists.asmx");
            }
```

I'm not sure you would want a solution like this. If you do, you may ask and i may publish the solution source for the webservice, however i'm not using this webservice myself anymore. And you could use it as a draft, not a production ready code.

The source has been published on [CodePlex](http://syncspviewoutlook.codeplex.com/).

### Regarding to the script problem

I don't know why list id isn't being replaced by view id. I tried to run the function within script console (F12 for IE8/9)

```
>> var menuItems = document.getElementsByTagName('ie:menuitem');
for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        itm = menuItems(i);
        if (itm.id.match('OfflineButton') != null) {
            console.log('listName:' + ctx.listName.toLowerCase() + 'viewName:' + ctx.view.toLowerCase());
            if (ctx != null && ctx.listName != null && ctx.view != null) {
                console.log('Inside if block');
                //Replace listId to viewId being used so outlook will query only items in current view.
                //Must have custom web service in place to handle that request, because it iwll not work OOTB.
        console.log("Before: " + itm.onMenuClick);
                itm.onMenuClick = itm.onMenuClick.replace(ctx.listName.toLowerCase(), ctx.view.toLowerCase());
        console.log("After: " + itm.onMenuClick);
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
LOG: listName:{fe89e809-7de4-4f43-9bc2-7e8ce6624ed0}viewName:{7364a843-c7f2-47d8-b4a3-5dc7381b6248} 
LOG: Inside if block 
LOG: Before: javaScript:ExportHailStorm('tasks','https:\u002f\u002fserver\u002fsapulces\u002fdarbu_parskata','{fe89e809-7de4-4f43-9bc2-7e8ce6624ed0}','Uz\u0146\u0113muma darbu p\u0101rskata sapulce','Uzdevumi','\u002fsapulces\u002fdarbu_parskata\u002fLists\u002fUzdevumi','','\u002fsapulces\u002fdarbu_parskata\u002fLists\u002fUzdevumi'); 
LOG: After: javaScript:ExportHailStorm('tasks','https:\u002f\u002fserver\u002fsapulces\u002fdarbu_parskata','{7364a843-c7f2-47d8-b4a3-5dc7381b6248}','Uz\u0146\u0113muma darbu p\u0101rskata sapulce','Uzdevumi','\u002fsapulces\u002fdarbu_parskata\u002fLists\u002fUzdevumi','','\u002fsapulces\u002fdarbu_parskata\u002fLists\u002fUzdevumi');
```

As you can see, the function argument (third one) has been replaced with a view id instead of list id.

Don't forget to remove console.log statements before deploying, because if IE doesn't have web developer tools, javascript will crash there.

Comment: There is a view in task list called My tasks that displays only task assigned to current logged in user. If I could connect this view to outlook, it would be great.

Comment: @Janis:I get the following error in outlook:

Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x80004005) : 'An error occured in the SharePoint List Try updating the folder again. If the problem continues, contact the Sharepoint site administrator. HTTP 500.

The server returned the following error message: Server was unable to process request. ---> Invalid URL provided contains an Invalid Command or VAlue. Pleae check the URL again. ---> Invalid URL parameter The URL provided contains an invalid Command or Value. Please check the URL again. I have copied the script along with my question

Comment: You may have to file up you visual studio debugger to see if 1. outlook requests sucessfully get redirected to OutlookLists.asmx 2. items are queried from SP sucessfully 3. what is the response that is beoing sent to Outlook. This will help identify where the problem is more closer. Also what version of Outlook are you using? I didn't try outlook 2003, but 2007.

Comment: The issue has been resolved but still the list id is being passed to OutlookLists.asmx and not the view Id. Am using 2007 only

Comment: See my answer please. Just ensure that third argument for ExportHailStorm is view id

Comment: Yes its getting replaced, but the error in outlook still remains

Comment: Anyways thanks for your time and help! I will take another look and let you know when it works.

Comment: Ah, then the problem isnt in the javascript part. If you have oppurtunity to fire up visual studio debugger, do so to identify the issue. Because if ID is being replaced but OutlookLists stil recieve old ID, then i think you assume that all current requests will request VIEW? No, they must reconnect the list to query specific view. If you cant use debugger, use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine and see messages with DebugView program

Answer (score 0):

Were these tasks created from a workflow? this is a known issue with SharePoint 2007.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/64b3b124-085c-4d8e-8e85-8bd20736e0e7

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-4-SharePoint_2007__Fine_grained_permission_control.aspx

You could try setting the read/edit permissions to "only their own", but i think that breaks approval/alerts from working

I believe the problem is fixed in SharePoint 2010, i think tasks get created with fine-grained permissions per task.

Comment: Yes the tasks were created from workflows. the task can be approved only by the person who has been assigned the task and the administrator. My application is in MOSS 2007 and migration to Sharepoit 2010 is definitely in the pipeline, but will take some time.