# Connecting SharePoint Calendar View to Outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, calendar, outlook

I am creating SharePoint solution.

I need to be able to connect calendar view to the Outlook. Really good solution is posted here: [Sharepoint task list and Outlook sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546811/sharepoint-task-list-and-outlook-sync)

But it doesn’t work due authentication problems: When I do ctx.RewritePath I get 401 error.

I am using SharePoint 2010 and Windows Authentication providers with NTLM. 
Currently I am trying to trick Outlook by writing HttpModule and trying inject correct result into response, but it’s not going well.

Are there any other solution to this problem?

Thank you,
Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up just creating a HttpModule that in context_PreRequestHandlerExecute gets the view and then constructs and returns SOAP back. 
Outlook seems to be happy.